# iOS - Stop hide of navigation bar when keyboard presents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

Simple issue. in iOS I have a `UIWebView` inside of a view controller. I push that view from another view controller. At this point, you always have a nav bar at the top of the view (with a back button that is titled with the name of the previous view).

There is a form inside my web view. When I click on a form field the navigation bar animates up out of view. Problem is that once you hide the keyboard by pressing done the nav bar doesn't come back.

I've found this to be the case actually with any view that has a `UITextField`.

Please help.

Comment: Your webview have textfield and when you focus on textfield keyboard show and navigationbar hide? This behavior from your webview or your code? And you have difference textfield except webview?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is

```
(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { }
```

inside this closure you want to close the navbar:

sth. like

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```